# How to change uploaded attachment filename with custom name in odoo

Tags: python, odoo

When I upload the attachment file, I want to display with custom name ,not with default filename.

Answer (score 2):

**Python Code**

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
_name = 'your.model'

image = fields.Binary('Image', required=True)
image_filename = fields.Char("Image Filename")
```

**XML View**

```
<record id="view_form_your_model" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Your Model Form</field>
    <field name="model">your.model</field>
    <field name="arch" type="XML">
        <form>
            <sheet>
                <group>
                    <field name="image_filename" invisible="0" />
                    <field widget="binary" name="image" filename="image_filename" />
                </group>
            </sheet>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>
```

Thanks

Comment: I want to use when user add the filename from char field and I want to display this when uploaded file from binary field as binary filename, now show the original filename.